# ¿Como inserto una imagen en un pdf, generado por la libreria pdfmake, desde javascript? en un proyecto en laravel

Tags: javascript, pdf, imagen, canvas, base64

Estoy empezando a utilizar la libreria y quiero insertar una imagen que se encuentra en la carpeta `public` de mi proyecto en `laravel`. Lo que llevo hasta el momento:

```
let docDefinition = {
    // a string or { width: number, height: number }
    pageSize: { width: 216 * pt, height: 279 * pt },

    // by default we use portrait, you can change it to landscape if you wish
    pageOrientation: 'portrait',

    // [left, top, right, bottom] or [horizontal, vertical] or just a number for equal margins
    pageMargins: [ 30 * pt, 30 * pt, 30 * pt, 30 * pt ],
    content: [
        {
            image: getBase64Image('{{ URL::asset('img/logo_cofasa.jpg') }}'),
        },
        'paragraph 1',
        'paragraph 2',
        {
            columns: [
            'first column is a simple text',
                {
                    stack: [
                        // second column consists of paragraphs
                        'paragraph A',
                        'paragraph B',
                        'these paragraphs will be rendered one below another inside the column'
                    ],
                    fontSize: 15
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('optionalName.pdf');

function getBase64Image(img) {
    // Create an empty canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // Copy the image contents to the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Get the data-URL formatted image
    // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to
    // guess the original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg"
    // will re-encode the image.
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

He leido y al capturar una imagen se debe convertir `Base64` y para eso se utiliza `canvas`. De esta manera que estoy intentando convertir la imagen a `base64` me genera este error en consola:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'
>       at getBase64Image (equipos:4174)
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (equipos:4141)
>       at HTMLTableSectionElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLTableSectionElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

**Actualizacion 1:**

Siguiendo la sugerencia de @lois6b, ya no me genera el error mostrado anteriormente.
Este error lo genera la libreria `pdfmake`:

> Uncaught invalid image, images dictionary should contain dataURL entries (or local file paths in node.js)

Este error se genera en el momento que intenta insertar la imagen:

```
{
    image: 'data:image/jpg;base64,'+getBase64Image('{{ URL::asset('img/logo_cofasa.jpg') }}'),
},
```

**Agrego:**

`{{ URL::asset('img/logo_cofasa.jpg') }}` me genera una url del archivo, ej: `sistematpm.local/img/logo_cofasa.jpg`

**Enlaces de la librería:**

[Acá la documentación](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted)

[Acá unos ejemplos de la librería](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html)

Comment: yo cuando uso `drawImage` lo que hago es usar un elemento `<img>` . Así que pasaria esa url como el `href` de la etiqueta `img` para poder hacer el `drawImage`. `ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById("imagen"),0,0);`

Comment: @lois6b primera vez que estoy llamando a archivos para mostrarlos, primera vez que use algo de canvas (si a eso se le llama usar) asi que ignoro el final de lo que dijiste ***Así que pasaria esa url como el href de la etiqueta img para poder hacer el drawImage.***.

Comment: Ahora a tu `getBase64Image` le estas pasando `'{{ URL::asset('img/logo_cofasa.jpg') }}'` (cuyo `URL::asset` desconozco) y el error parece que es que la variable `img` no es del tipo correcto. asi que a tu metodo pasale el elemento `<img href="/tu/imagen.jpg" hidden>`.

Comment: @lois6b Se soluciono el error del `drawImage`, solventandolo de la manera como me sugeriste, pero ahora me envía un error la librería `pdfmake`.